# ChoiceType inside form send key and not value

Tags: symfony

I have a ThemePlace entity with only two field (id and value).

I have a PlaceType form and in this form I would like to print in a select list all the themes values.

This is what I have in my PlaceType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('content')
        ->add('title')
        ->add('theme', ChoiceType::class, [
            'choices' => $options['themes'],
        ])
        ->add('maxUser')
        ->add('longitude')
        ->add('latitude')
        ->add('avatarPath',FileType::class, array('data_class' => null,'required' => false));
}/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Place',
        'themes' => 'AppBundle\Entity\ThemePlace'
    ));
}
```

But in my view I got `0 / 1 / 2` instead of having `Theme1 / Theme2 / Theme3`

```
{{ form_widget(form.theme) }}
{{ form_errors(form.theme) }}
```

I've seen some topics on stack speaking of using choice_value inside the builder but I can't make it work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

symfony's ChoiceType is a bit different:

the choices array has the structure: `{displayed value} => {actual value}`

(this is probably due to the fact, that values are often enough more complex than a string, while display values are almost always strings - or at least it doesn't hurt to turn them into strings.)

I assume you have `[theme1,theme2,theme3]` which is short for

```
[
  0 => theme1, 
  1 => theme2, 
  2 => theme3,
]
```

If the themes are strings, you could just double them:

```
[
  theme1 => theme1,
  theme2 => theme2,
  theme3 => theme3,
]
```

if they are entities, use the `EntityType` instead of the `ChoiceType` (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#reference-forms-entity-choices)

```
$builder->add('themes', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => Theme::class, // your class here!
    'choices' => $options['themes'],
    'choice_label' => function($theme) { 
         return $theme->getName(); // <-- use your display value
    },
]);
```

however, you may have to add a toString to the Theme entity instead, or use a property path instead of the anonymous function in the `choice_label` option.

Comment: My themes coming from the controller into the builder is the simple result of findAll().
So I'm not building directly in the builder; that's why I'm stuck.

Comment: @Minirock if it's the result of a findAll, use EntityType instead: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#reference-forms-entity-choices (however, this is expanding the question). don't forget the toString method on the entity. if you have further problems, consider opening a new question and/or doing research yourself ;o) no offense ,o)